# Dynamically binding title tag in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm new to vuejs.

I try to bind data on the title tag dynamically. I used vue-head to do this on a simple html page. I do not use webpack and npm.

This is how I bind the title tag :

```
var app = new Vue({
            el: 'html',
            head: {
              title: function () {
                return {
                    inner: this.remaining + ' Tâches',
                    separator: ' ',
                    complement: ' '   
                }
              }
            }
```

In the vue-head documentation, they suggest to do this :

```
methods: {
  getAsyncData: function () {
    var self = this
    window.setTimeout(function () {
    self.title = 'My async title'
    self.$emit('updateHead')
    }, 3000)
  }
},
```

I also tried to set it in the watch prop, but it didn't work.

Here is my entire code : https://jsfiddle.net/5d70s0s6/1/

Thanks

Comment: It's working for me. I can see the `title` tag being set in your fiddle.

Comment: Yep, it works but if I change a task, I want the title to update dynamically. Like the {{ remaining }} in the fiddle. Now, I have to reload the page to change the title tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36612847/how-can-i-bind-the-html-title-content-in-vuejs

Comment: I already saw that question, but the solutions doesn't work for me. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I bind the html <title> content in vuejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36612847/how-can-i-bind-the-html-title-content-in-vuejs)

Comment: @SahnaS What exactly did not work with that solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `computed` property.

```
computed: {
  title: {
    get() {
      document.title = this.remaining
      return this.remaining
    },
    set(val) {
      document.title = val
    }
  }
}
```

You don't need to use `<title>{{title}}</title>`. If you change `title` in your Vue, it will be applied automatically to the page.

Also, you should not bind a Vue instance to `html`, `head` or `body` tags. Use regular elements only like `<div id="app"></div>` and set your Vue `el: '#app'`

Or you could use this:

```
data: {
  title: '',
},
watch: {
  title(val) {
    document.title = val
  }
}
```

**Update:**
While the code above can solve your problem. I created this *tiny* [vue-title component](https://github.com/ikbelkirasan/vue-title) that can be used in your project easily.

Example:

```
<vue-title>{{title}}</vue-title>
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but it did not work for me. How can I bind it to the title tag? By using {{ title }} ?

Comment: It should work if your Vue instance is bound to `html` element. If you're testing it in a jsfiddle it won't work because it's inside an iframe.

Comment: I try it in my localhost using sublimText and sublimServer and it's not works. Maybe I didn't do it well, I'm a totally beginner with Vuejs. Thanks

Comment: Have I to change this : app.$mount('.todoapp') to this : app.$mount('html') ? Because if I do this, it will breaks all the app.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly, but if I include this in the rest of my code, it do not works. Maybe there is something in my code who "breaks" your solution. I can't find why.

Comment: When I add your solution, my code works exactly like my old one. I have to reload the page to update the title tag. 

This is my js part : https://pastebin.com/TQMnm2MU

And I added the v-model="title" in my title. 

EDIT : I notice that your solution is binding to an input, but my code isn't an input, but a function result. 

Thanks

Comment: It don't works. The title is empty with your updated solution.

Comment: I simplified the solution, try again

Comment: Thanks ! It's ok with your solution + bind Vuejs to the HTML tag.