# How can I make title bar dynamic on vuetify?

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-component, url-routing, vuetify.js

I see vuetify project have title bar. But the title in public/index.html. Outside src folder

So I had trouble making it dynamic. Every page must have different title. If it's same, it's very influential on SEO

My public/index.html like this :

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <title>test-vuetify</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@latest/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but test-vuetify doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I solve this problem? I want to make title on every page is different. According to page content

Comment: Where are you getting the page content from? Is it hard-coded or pulled from some DB? If it's from some DB, you would simply set the title data the same way you set the body data

Comment: @EGC There exist data from the database and there exist data is hard-coded

Comment: Looks like you can make your own component to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36612847/how-can-i-bind-the-html-title-content-in-vuejs

Comment: @Damian C  Is this method really useful for SEO? if I right-click on my website and select `View Page Source`, I see the title, description, keywords don't change. I look doubtful this way is correct

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell exactly what your constraints are from the question, but in case this helps anyone else make their Vuetify title bar dynamic...

In `index.js`, add some "meta" to the routes:

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/page1',
    name: 'page-1',
    component: ...,
    meta: {
      title: 'Page 1'
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/page2',
    name: 'page-2',
    component: ...,
    meta: {
      title: 'Page 2'
    }
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: (your base url),
  routes: routes,
});

export default router
```

Then in the Vuetify title bar, use the route meta defined above:

```
<v-toolbar-title>{{ $route.meta.title || "Default title" }}</v-toolbar-title>
```