# How can I solve Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-headful'.?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, npm

My project using vuetify

I try to install vue-headful for seo.

The reference :

https://github.com/troxler/vue-headful

[How can I bind the html <title> content in vuejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36612847/how-can-i-bind-the-html-title-content-in-vuejs)

I try it and it works. but in my main.js exist error like this :

[image]

I try : `npm install @types/vue-headful`

there exist error :

`npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fvue-headful - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@types/vue-headful@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Duplicate of [Could not find a declaration file for module 'module-name'. '/path/to/module-name.js' implicitly has an 'any' type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292559/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-module-name-path-to-module-nam)

Comment: vue-headful does not have typings. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50516783/906113).