# Cypress test fails for asserting equal to DOM title

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, cypress, vue-cli-4

Working on a project created with the `@vue/cli 4.2.2` and [Vue CLI Electron Plugin Builder](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/). Vue CLI uses the [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/) that automatically generates the `index.html` in the `public` directory. The `</title>` of the relevant `index.html` page has the `<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %>` syntax that automatically detects the title of the page from the `vue.config.js` file.

`vue.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
      chainWebpackRendererProcess: config => {
        config.plugin("html").tap(args => {
          args[0].title = "Stack Overflow";
          return args;
        });
      }
    }
  }
};
```

The problem is that when the app starts, there's a millisecond flash where the page title changes from **stackoverflow** to **Stack Overflow**. To prevent this, I used the Electron `page-title-updated` hook like the following to make sure the app title loads correctly.

`main.js`

```js
var win = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 800, 
  height: 600,
  title: 'Stack Overflow'
});

win.on('page-title-updated', (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault();
});
```

It works great and there's no window flashing in the `</title>` now but when running `e2e` test using the Cypress, it just can't find the correct title **Stack Overflow** and test fails.
`test.js`

```js
describe("My First Test", () => {
  it("ensures the correct title", () => {
    cy.visit('/').title().should('eq', 'Stack Overflow')
  })
});
```

The result of Cypress test `expected stackoverflow to equal Stack Overflow`. So, the million dollar question is, how do I get the Cypress test pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are testing via Vue's script `test:e2e`, it looks like the test target is the Vue app in the browser, not the electron app.

Of course, you can set title in the Vue app as per this question [How can I bind the html  content in vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36612847/how-can-i-bind-the-html-title-content-in-vuejs) (as well as your mod to the Electon startup) and your Electron app still looks ok.

**Title.vue**

```js
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'vue-title',
    props: ['title'],
    watch: {
      title: {
        immediate: true,
        handler() {
          document.title = this.title;
        }
      }
    },
    render () {
      return null;
    },
  }
</script>
```

**App.vue**

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Title title="Stack Overflow"></Title>
    ...
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Title from './components/Title.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Title
  },
}
</script>
```

Now the test passes, but you are still just testing Vue code, not as running in Electron.

See [Testing Electron.js applications using Cypress - alpha release](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/09/26/testing-electron-js-applications-using-cypress-alpha-release/) for some info that may help you.