# How to remove stylesheet when changing page in Vue

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-4, vue-router, vuejs3

As a beginner of Vue.js, I am trying to remove stylesheet which I added through the `mounted` lifecycle in a component with

```
 mounted() {
     this.style = document.createElement('link');
     this.style.type = "text/css";
     this.style.href = 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css';
     document.head.append(this.style);
 }
```

This works fine. When I visit this page, I can see the effect of the Bootstrap. However, when I change to another component through `router-view`, I want to remove this stylesheet to affect other pages. I tried `remove` like appending the stylesheet, but it doesn't work:

```
unmounted() {
    document.head.remove(this.style);
}
```

**UPDATE**
It seems that this works when I refresh the page or use `$router.go(0)` to refresh it but how can I remove the stylesheet without refreshing the page.

Comment: My first thought was instead of building the stylesheet link tag at runtime, possibly binding Vue to a link tag in the head section, which I haven't done.  After a brief search, I found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36612847/how-can-i-bind-the-html-title-content-in-vuejs) which may be applicable.  Possibly you could add/remove the href value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `HTMLLinkElement` instance can be removed with [`.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove):

```js
unmounted() {
    this.style.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try to disable it with
`this.style.disabled=true`
and don't do it in unmounted, since chances are good that there's no "this" as the component has been removed already. there's also a `beforeUnmount` or sth. like that.